# Fusebox cannot identify the controller

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo, cfc, fusebox

I am creating a fusebox application in Fusebox 5. It is working fine in my local. When I try it in a railo server, it throws an error like Attempting to execute the parsed file 'MyController.main.cfm' threw an error.

> This can occur if the parsed file does not exist in the parsed
>   directory or if the parsed directory itself is missing

in the OnRequest of the core application file. It happens in the line `<cfinclude template="#_parsedFileData.parsedFile#" />` and when I dumped the variable it shows like `../../../../../:\projects\Mydomain\MyAppName\/parsed/MyController.main.cfm.` The file path is strange as the Mydomain is my host name where I am having my application(MyAppName is the application name). Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: A bit OT, but you might want to consider something a little more modern than Fusebox.

Comment: @JamesAMohler It is good to see the opt choice for the requirements. But they want me to do this way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be caused by a conflict between a UDF in Fusebox and a built-in function with the same name in Railo/Lucee.

Try searching the entire Fusebox folder for `getCanonicalPath` and replacing each occurrence with `getCanonicalPathUdf`.